# Time Summing Issue with PL-SQL Linked Excel File

Tags: excel, oracle, time, plsql, toad

Going to try my best to explain this issue thoroughly, as I've spent literally days and days trying to figure out a fix to this problem to no avail.

I have some excel report templates I have built that reference Five9 Call Data exports. I've been manually having to export the data from the Five9 application on a regular basis to refresh these reports, so I decided to make my process more efficient and automated by coding my exports and having them link directly to my excel workbook reports for easy refreshing.

I have basic T-SQL experience, but realized I would need PL-SQL experience since this is an Oracle based DB. After a couple days I figured out how to code the exports I need in PL-SQL and set them up into linked excel workbooks. But then I ran into the issue...

My reports rely on being able to SUM the Time data from my exports, but my SUM formulas are now resulting in Zero when they shouldn't. The issue is not a matter of formatting the columns to Time ([h]:mm:ss...yes that was my first thought too). The issue is that the data is literally not recognized as a time at all and is recognized as text. 
This article explains the exact issue I'm experiencing: http://theexceltrainer.co.uk/adding-up-times-in-excel-results-in-zero/

The problem is it doesn't give me a reasonable workaround. If I do the text-to-columns trick they suggest that will not stick when I go to refresh the data the next time I need to refresh the report (the times will revert back to being identified as text). The whole purpose of me coding out my exports was to make this process completely automated, so having to go in and reformat (do the text-to-columns thing) each time completely defeats the purpose.

Is there no other workaround for this? Possibly something to add into the code that will make excel recognize the time as actual time and not text? The problem did not exist when I used to manually export the data as a CSV file...but I can't (or at least I don't know how) to setup a PL-SQL linked excel file that is also CSV. I'm at a loss...

I have included my code, if that helps:

```
SELECT 
CALL_DATE as "Date"
, CALL_TIME as "Time"
, CALL_TIMESTAMP as "Timestamp"
, RING_TIME as "Ring Time"
, DIAL_TIME as "Dial Time"
, CALL_TIME_2 as "Call Time"
, AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME as "After Call Work Time"
, CAMPAIGN as "Campaign"
, CAMPAIGN_TYPE as "Campaign Type"
, CALL_TYPE as "Call Type"
, DISPOSITION as "Disposition"
, AGENT_GROUP as "Agent Group"
, AGENT_NAME as "Agent Name"
, SALESFORCE_ID as "Salesforce ID"

FROM Comp_DB.FIVE9_CALLS

WHERE 
AGENT_GROUP = 'Collections'
and TRUNC(CALL_DATE) BETWEEN '01-June-2017' and TRUNC(SYSDATE)

ORDER BY
CALL_DATE asc
```

RING_TIME, DIAL_TIME, CALL_TIME_2 and AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME are the fields I need to be able to SUM. They already pull in the correct format of "hh:mm:ss"...but Excel still isn't recognizing them as time...

Comment: you can try to format the date on the output so the fomat will be recongnized by excel?
select to_char(date_column,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from mytable;

Answer (score 0):

First hand could I recommend replacing that string in your WHERE clause for something like this? :

```
TRUNC(CALL_DATE) BETWEEN to_date('01-06-2017','dd-mm-yyyy') and TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

so that you don't let Oracle engine to (hopefully) resolve your date value.

Now for your problem, maybe you can do your "math" within the query as opposed to do it in Excel, as in:

```
SELECT 
CALL_DATE as "Date"
, CALL_TIME as "Time"
, CALL_TIMESTAMP as "Timestamp"
, RING_TIME as "Ring Time"
, DIAL_TIME as "Dial Time"
, CALL_TIME_2 as "Call Time"
, AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME as "After Call Work Time"
, CAMPAIGN as "Campaign"
, CAMPAIGN_TYPE as "Campaign Type"
, CALL_TYPE as "Call Type"
, DISPOSITION as "Disposition"
, AGENT_GROUP as "Agent Group"
, AGENT_NAME as "Agent Name"
, SALESFORCE_ID as "Salesforce ID"
, numtodsinterval(
         (SUBSTR(RING_TIME, 1, 2)*3600 + SUBSTR(RING_TIME, 4, 2)*60 + SUBSTR(RING_TIME, 7, 2))+
         (SUBSTR(DIAL_TIME, 1, 2)*3600 + SUBSTR(DIAL_TIME, 4, 2)*60 + SUBSTR(DIAL_TIME, 7, 2))+
         (SUBSTR(CALL_TIME_2, 1, 2)*3600 + SUBSTR(CALL_TIME_2, 4, 2)*60 + SUBSTR(CALL_TIME_2, 7, 2))+
         (SUBSTR(AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME, 1, 2)*3600 + SUBSTR(AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME, 4, 2)*60 + SUBSTR(AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME, 7, 2))
         , 'SECOND') as "Total duration"
FROM Comp_DB.FIVE9_CALLS

WHERE 
AGENT_GROUP = 'Collections'
and TRUNC(CALL_DATE) BETWEEN to_date('01-06-2017','dd-mm-yyyy') and TRUNC(SYSDATE)

ORDER BY
CALL_DATE asc
```

Which basically subdivide the time elements (hour, minute) from every field, gets their representation in seconds, makes the addition for all your desired columns and in the end converts the resulting seconds into a 'date to second' interval with `numtodsinterval`.

Note that I'm assuming from your OP that the fields

> already pull in the correct format of "hh:mm:ss"

and so the `substr` functions are pulling out the elements for hour, minute, second, in that expected position order.

PS: The method I'd just described helps you with a row-level summation and not a column-level one, please specify which one you do actually need, so we could provide a better answer.